# Oracle SQL Most Recent Row based on Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this question has been asked a lot of times on the forum and I've attempted multiple ways of getting what I need to always have some error message so i'm losing the will to live trying to debug it. I'm writing the SQL in Oracle Fusion 13C

The message i'm getting is "Too Many Values" and I'm pretty sure it's coming from my final where clause. The code without the final line brings back two rows of data that are correct, I want to only bring back one though based on which row has the latest date in the "ACTION_DATE" column or, failing that the highest number in the "SEQUENCE_NUM" column.

The code I've got so far is:

```
WITH
PERSON_DETAILS AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                    PERSON_ID AS PPNPERSONID,
                    FULL_NAME
                FROM
                    PER_PERSON_NAMES_F
                WHERE
                    TO_DATE(EFFECTIVE_END_DATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd') > TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
                    AND NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL'

),

PERSON_ASSIGNMENT AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                        PD.*,
                        PAAM.PERSON_ID AS PAAMPERSONID,
                        PAAM.JOB_ID AS PAAMJOBID
                    FROM
                        PERSON_DETAILS PD,
                        PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM
                    WHERE
                        PD.PPNPERSONID = PAAM.PERSON_ID
                        AND TO_DATE(PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd') > TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd')

),

PERSON_JOB AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                PA.*,
                PJF.JOB_ID AS PJFJOBID,
                PJF.APPROVAL_AUTHORITY
            FROM
                PERSON_ASSIGNMENT PA,
                PER_JOBS_F PJF
            WHERE
                PA.PAAMJOBID = PJF.JOB_ID
                AND TO_DATE(PJF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd') > TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd')



),

REQ_APPROVER_DETAIL AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                        PJ.*,
                        PAH.OBJECT_TYPE_CODE ,
                        PAH.SEQUENCE_NUM ,
                        PAH.ACTION_CODE ,
                        PAH.ACTION_DATE ,
                        PAH.PERFORMER_ID,
                        PAH.OBJECT_ID AS PAHOBJECTID
                    FROM
                        FUSION.PO_ACTION_HISTORY PAH,
                        PERSON_JOB PJ
                    WHERE
                        PAH.PERFORMER_ID = PJ.PPNPERSONID
                        AND ACTION_CODE = 'APPROVE'

),
REQ_DETAIL AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                RAD.*,
                RHA.requisition_number AS Req_Number,
                RHA.requisition_header_id RHAREQHEADID

            FROM
                REQ_APPROVER_DETAIL RAD,
                FUSION.POR_REQUISITION_HEADERS_ALL RHA
            WHERE
                RAD.PAHOBJECTID = RHA.requisition_header_id

),

REQ_LINE_DETAIL AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                    RD.*,
                    SUM(rla.unit_price*rla.quantity) AS QUANTITY_AMOUNT,
                    SUM(rla.amount) AS AMOUNT_ORDERED
                FROM
                    POR_REQUISITION_LINES_ALL RLA,
                    REQ_DETAIL RD
                WHERE
                    RD.RHAREQHEADID = RLA.requisition_header_id
                GROUP BY
                    RHAREQHEADID,
                    Req_Number,
                    OBJECT_TYPE_CODE,
                    SEQUENCE_NUM,
                    ACTION_CODE,
                    ACTION_DATE,
                    PERFORMER_ID,
                    PAHOBJECTID,
                    PJFJOBID,
                    APPROVAL_AUTHORITY,
                    PPNPERSONID,
                    FULL_NAME,
                    PAAMPERSONID,
                    PAAMJOBID



),

REQ_TOTAL_AMOUNT AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                    RLD.*,
                    CASE WHEN RLD.AMOUNT_ORDERED IS NULL THEN 
RLD.QUANTITY_AMOUNT
                        ELSE RLD.AMOUNT_ORDERED
                            END AS REQ_AMOUNT_TOTAL
                    FROM
                        REQ_LINE_DETAIL RLD
)

SELECT 
Req_Number,
FULL_NAME,
SEQUENCE_NUM,
REQ_AMOUNT_TOTAL,
--OBJECT_TYPE_CODE,
ACTION_DATE,
--ACTION_CODE
--APPROVAL_AUTHORITY


FROM REQ_TOTAL_AMOUNT

--WHERE PPNPERSONID = '300000008160059'
WHERE REQ_NUMBER = '702387'
AND ACTION_DATE = (SELECT 
MAX(PAH.ACTION_DATE),PAH.PERFORMER_ID FROM FUSION.PO_ACTION_HISTORY PAH, PER_PERSON_NAMES_F PPN WHERE PAH.PERFORMER_ID = PPN.PERSON_ID)
```

Thank you for any help you can give. I've debugged it down to the last WHERE clause in the last SELECT. If I remove it/comment out the final line it works bringing back two lines. The data that i've brought back so far is:

```
REQ_Number|FULL_NAME|SEQUENCE_NUM|REQ_TOTAL_AMOUNT|ACTION_DATE
702387     Sam Jones    3          £19,000         2017-08-23T12:08:39.000+00:00
702387     Bill Baggins  4         £19,000         2017-08-23T13:55:55.000+00:00
```

I want to bring back just the row for Bill Baggins as it was the one that was actioned latest out of the two rows but if it can't be done on the Action_Date then the SEQUENCE_NUM would bring it back also as 4 > 3 etc

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry again as this question no doubt has been asked plenty of times

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt.  The final predicate you mentioned looks like it is selecting two things: the `MAX(PAH.ACTION_DATE)` and the `PAH.PERFORMER_ID`, but it is used in an equality comparison to `ACTION_DATE`.  The sql engine will have trouble comparing one item to two items.  What happens if you throw out the `PAH.PERFORMER_ID` and use just the `MAX(PAH.ACTION_DATE)` in your final subquery?  The final subquery likely couldn't execute standalone anyway, as `PERFORMER_ID` is not an aggregate nor a partitioning key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is your problem:

```
AND ACTION_DATE = (SELECT MAX(PAH.ACTION_DATE), PAH.PERFORMER_ID 
                     FROM FUSION.PO_ACTION_HISTORY PAH, PER_PERSON_NAMES_F PPN 
                    WHERE PAH.PERFORMER_ID = PPN.PERSON_ID)
```

Your subquery returns two columns, `MAX(PAH.ACTION_DATE)`, and `PAH.PERFORMER_ID`, but you're checking that with `=` against just `ACTION_DATE`. So you're comparing one column against two, which doesn't work.

You can do something like this with `(ACTION_DATE, <some other column>) = ...`, but I'm pretty sure this won't even parse, since you have no `GROUP BY` clause in the subquery. In any case, that subquery **must** return only a single row or you will get "ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row."

I suspect your subquery isn't what you want and you want to remove `pah.performer_id`  and add a clause that correlates it to the main query, perhaps `AND PAH.PERFORMER_ID = REQ_TOTAL_AMOUNT.PPNPERSONID`, maybe?